# Arduino equivalent to VB WITH

Tags: c++, struct, typedef

Is there an Arduino equivalent to the Visual BASIC "with" concept?

If I have and Arduino struct as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  int present = 0; // position now
  int demand = 0;  // required position
} superStruct;

superStruct super;
```

I could say

```
if (super.present > super.demand) { super.present-=1; }
```

is there a means by which I might foreshorten it to

```
with super {
  if (.present > .demand) { .present-=1; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your concern? Reducing typing, or something else?

Comment: Ease of reading. Reducing typing is an added bonus. In fact, all the concerns which existed when they invented "WITH" in VB.

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Fancy converting that to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to complement John Bode's answer: note that a method of the struct¹
can access the members without prefix:

```
struct superStruct {
  int present = 0; // position now
  int demand = 0;  // required position
  void update_position() {
    if (present > demand) { present-=1; }
  }
};

superStruct super;

super.update_position();
```

¹a struct in C++ is just a class with all members public by default.

Comment: I think I would normally only wish to access the members by a method. This may actually be what I seek.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent syntax in C++; you must specify the `struct` instance along with the member.